# Using Cell Array Contents to Create Struct Entries

Tags: matlab, structure, cell-array

Say that I have two cell arrays, A and B, that contain string values. I wish to populate a struct S such I generate every possible combination of `S.valueinA.valueinB = 1`. I am currently trying to accomplish this with two nested for-loops that iterate through every possible combination and wanted to ask if there is a more efficient way to solve this problem in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make dynamic field names in structures, I don't see how else you can do it without two `for` loops.  Let's say we have two cell arrays `A` and `B` that consist of string entries.
For my example, apologies for the strings inside these arrays in advance as I couldn't think of anything better at the moment!

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
S = struct();
A = {'hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'ray'};
B = {'i', 'am', 'doing', 'awesome'};
for idx = 1 : numel(A)
    for idx2 = 1 : numel(B)
        S.(A{idx}).(B{idx2}) = 1;
    end
end
```

This creates a nested structure `S` such that for each element in `A`, this becomes a field in `S` where this field is **another** structure that contains fields with names coming from all elements in `B`.

If we displayed `S`, we get:

```
>> S

S = 

    hello: [1x1 struct]
       my: [1x1 struct]
     name: [1x1 struct]
       is: [1x1 struct]
      ray: [1x1 struct]
```

If we accessed the `hello` field of `S`, we get:

```
>> S.hello

ans = 

          i: 1
         am: 1
      doing: 1
    awesome: 1
```

Similarly, if we accessed the `my` field, we get:

```
>> S.my

ans = 

          i: 1
         am: 1
      doing: 1
    awesome: 1
```

Therefore, if we want to get the `hello` field followed by the `am` field, we do:

```
>> S.hello.am

ans =

     1
```

Comment: @nkjt - lol.  thank you very much.  that comment made my morning.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the answer! This is in fact what I was trying to achieve; I was trying to research whether matlab had a more efficient method (since this could take really long over thousands of entries).

Comment: @mCode - Ah I gotcha.  Yeah when it comes to dynamic field names, I don't see how you could do this without a `for` loop.  However, if the nested field consists of just a single number, then I think it should be relatively fast.  I haven't tested it yet, but that's my hunch.  You're welcome  btw!